# Dropping of connections with tcp_tw_recycle

Tags: linux, tcp

## summary of the problem

we are having a setup wherein a lot(800 to 2400 per second) of incoming connections to a linux box and we have a NAT device between the client and server.
so there are so many TIME_WAIT sockets left in the system.
To overcome that we had set tcp_tw_recycle to 1, but that led to drop of in comming connections.
after browsing through the net we did find the references for why the dropping of frames with tcp_tw_recycle and NAT device happens.

## resolution tried

we then tried by setting tcp_tw_reuse to 1 it worked fine without any issues with the same setup and configuration.

But the documentation says that tcp_tw_recycle and tcp_tw_reuse should not be used when the    Connections that go through TCP state aware nodes, such as firewalls, NAT devices or load balancers may see dropped frames. The more connections there are, the more likely you will see this issue.

## Queries

1. can tcp_tw_reuse be used in this type of scenarios?
2. if not, which part of the linux code is preventing tcp_tw_reuse being used for such scenario?
3. generally what is the difference between tcp_tw_recycle and tcp_tw_reuse?

Answer (score 58):

By default, when both `tcp_tw_reuse` and `tcp_tw_recycle` are disabled, the kernel will make sure that sockets in `TIME_WAIT` state will remain in that state long enough -- long enough to be sure that packets belonging to future connections will not be mistaken for late packets of the old connection.

When you enable `tcp_tw_reuse`, sockets in `TIME_WAIT` state can be used before they expire, and the kernel will try to make sure that there is no collision regarding TCP sequence numbers. If you enable `tcp_timestamps` (a.k.a. PAWS, for Protection Against Wrapped Sequence Numbers), it will make sure that those collisions cannot happen. However, you need TCP timestamps to be enabled on *both* ends (at least, that's my understanding). See the [definition of tcp_twsk_unique](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=tcp_twsk_unique) for the gory details.

When you enable `tcp_tw_recycle`, the kernel becomes much more aggressive, and will make assumptions on the timestamps used by remote hosts. It will track the last timestamp used by each remote host having a connection in `TIME_WAIT` state), and allow to re-use a socket if the timestamp has correctly increased. However, if the timestamp used by the host changes (i.e. warps back in time), the `SYN` packet will be silently dropped, and the connection won't establish (you will see an error similar to "connect timeout"). If you want to dive into kernel code, the [definition of tcp_timewait_state_process](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=tcp_timewait_state_process) might be a good starting point.

Now, timestamps should never go back in time; unless:

- the host is rebooted (but then, by the time it comes back up, `TIME_WAIT` socket will probably have expired, so it will be a non issue);
- the IP address is quickly reused by something else (`TIME_WAIT` connections will stay a bit, but other connections will probably be struck by `TCP RST` and that will free up some space);
- **network address translation** (or a smarty-pants firewall) is involved in the middle of the connection.

In the latter case, you can have multiple hosts behind the same IP address, and therefore, different sequences of timestamps (or, said timestamps are randomized at each connection by the firewall). In that case, some hosts will be randomly unable to connect, because they are mapped to a port for which the `TIME_WAIT` bucket of the server has a newer timestamp. That's why the docs tell you that "NAT devices or load balancers may start drop frames because of the setting".

Some people recommend to leave `tcp_tw_recycle` alone, but enable `tcp_tw_reuse` and lower `tcp_fin_timeout`. I concur :-)

Comment: Link at bottom broken

Comment: Great thanks. I encountered exactly this case --hosts behind NAT will randomly unable to connect, and disabling net.ipv4.timestamps just got everything fine(tcp_tw_recycle and tcp_tw_reuse are both enabled on both machine).

Comment: I believe, it should be `tcp_fin_timeout` and not `tcp_timewait_len`. But perhaps it changed in the kernel versions?

Comment: tcp_tw_recycle has been removed as of Linux 4.12.  This is because Linux now randomizes timestamps per connection and they do not monotonically increase.  If you're using Linux 4.12 with machines using tcp_tw_recycle and TCP timestamps are turned on you will see dropped connections.  You can of course disable it like so `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_timestamps` (temporarily, use sysctl.conf for permanent changes).  Details on 4.12 removing tcp_tw_recycle: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=4396e46187ca5070219b81773c4e65088dac50cc