# tcp_tw_recycle behind application level load balancer?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Given that our linux servers never open direct connections to our clients, is it safe to use tcp_tw_recycle on them ?

Those servers are behind a application level load-balancer and all the connections i see on them are between internal 10.x.x.x addresses.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have such a load balancer provided by AWS (ELB), so I'll provide my advice based on that:

Why gamble? If your overhead/port-consumption is coming from quick client connections, Amazon recommends enabling persistent connections on your ELB instead. (I asked them about this question specifically and got that recommendation...our Amazon contact does not recommend enabling tcp_tw_recycle).

That said, if, say it's another internal box they're struggling to establish rapid connections with (apache-php chatting with MySQL on behalf of the client without persistent connections), you might be able to get away with it:

If ALL client connections will be via the ELB (please set your security group accordingly), then technically speaking you shouldn't encounter problems for the tcp_tw_recycle timestamp jumping cases I'm aware of:

1. ELB is a termination point on behalf of the client (their NAT firewall won't factor in, and ELB is not NAT based)
2. The ELB box(es) will not reset themselves, acquire the same IP address, and still be assigned as your ELB (will be someone else's if it happens at all)
3. The ELB box(es) will not be replaced by another ELB machine using the same IP and still be serving your traffic as your ELB (will be someone else's if it happens at all)

*2 and 3 are not a guarantee from Amazon, but it does appear to be their behavior, just as stop/start will get you a new private IP for EC2 boxes). If that did happen, I'd imagine it is a thing of extremely low probability.

You could theoretically run into issues restarting your own boxes if they communicate with other service machines (like MySQL or memcached) and you restart (not stop/start) one of your boxes, or move their elastic IP to another box and are not using private IPs for internal chatter. But you have some control over this. However, if it's all on the AWS cloud (or your fast internal network), issues are extremely unlikely (unless your AWS zone is having a bad day, and you're restarting/replacing your systems for that reason).

A buddy and I had a long-standing argument about this, and he won by proving his point with a long running 4k browser (fast script) load test via Neustar...there were no connection issues from the client side via ELB, and eliminating the overhead helped quite a bit :-)

If you haven't already, consider tcp_tw_reuse (we were using this to keep the ephemeral port range active before the above mentioned test showed the additional merit of eliminating the overhead with tcp_tw_recycle for us). Be sure to watch your counters on ifconfig if you do decide to disable that chunk of the protocol ;-P.

The following is also a good summary resource on the topic of timestamps jumping: [Dropping of connections with tcp_tw_recycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893888/dropping-of-connections-with-tcp-tw-recycle)