# Dropping of connections when kernel parameter tcp_tw_recycle is enabled

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

Our API which is having 600 request per min access, the API setup is using two dedicated servers one for php process and second for mariadb. We are using 14 core,  128 ram servers for both.

The communication between  api and database server is happening via local network, when ever there is large access towards api we have noticed two errors one on api larvel log and second on mysql server side.

> production.ERROR:
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Maximum
>   execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
>
> [Warning] Aborted connection 48520867 to db: 'database-name' user:
>   'root' host: '172.16.1.2' (Got timeout reading communication packets)

We have managed to fix the api error by making two changes, php max_execution_time to 120 seconds and setting kernel parameter net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1,

Once this is done we are now facing connection drop from our Office ISP with dedicated IP address, we have more than 100 users connecting from same IP.

Once the kernel parameter "net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1" is disabled our office IP can access it cool.   We already have "net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1".

What is the possible solution for these ?  I could also see a stackoverflow discussion which is almost similar to the same issue. But still unable to  find a solution for the same.

[Dropping of connections with tcp_tw_recycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893888/dropping-of-connections-with-tcp-tw-recycle)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem arise due to the more number of connections between the PHP and Maria DB.

Please increase the number of request that can be handled by Apache, and increase the buffer memory size of the Maria DB.

In Mysql we can increase the below mentioned parameters (Not worked with Maria DB till now)

```
/etc/my.cnf
***innodb_buffer_pool_size = 384M***
key_buffer = 256M
query_cache_size = 1M
query_cache_limit = 128M
thread_cache_size = 8
***max_connections = 400***
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 100
```

Please have a try.

Comment: We have already done those,

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 90GB
innodb_thread_concurrency = 48
imax_connections  = 65535
connect_timeout  = 5
wait_timeout  = 600
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
thread_cache_size       = 128
sort_buffer_size = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size  = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M

Comment: Have you increased the Apache web server MaxClients to process value?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389496/how-do-you-increase-the-max-number-of-concurrent-connections-in-apache

Answer (score 0):

The setting "net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0"   has completely fixed the dropping of connections.   Working good.  We can set  net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle to 0 by using the below command.

> sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=0

**Reference discussions :-**

[tcp_tw_reuse vs tcp_tw_recycle : Which to use (or both)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426253/tcp-tw-reuse-vs-tcp-tw-recycle-which-to-use-or-both)

https://serverfault.com/questions/234534/is-it-dangerous-to-change-the-value-of-proc-sys-net-ipv4-tcp-tw-reuse